# Duplicating scores after two or more attempts in online exam

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a school web app that has an online exam feature## Heading ##Students are given a number of times they can attempt the exam.

However, when a student attempts the exam two or more times and saves, the scores are duplicated in the database instead of being updated.

I will like that when a student attempts an exam again, the previous scores are overwritten or replaced not duplicated.

[image: duplicated online exam scores]

Controller:

```
 public function save()
 {

 if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {
 $total_rows = $this->input->post('total_rows');

 if (!empty($total_rows)) {
 $save_result = array();
 foreach ($total_rows as $row_key => $row_value) {
 if (($_POST['question_type_' . $row_value]) == "singlechoice") {

 if (isset($_POST['radio' . $row_value])) {
 $save_result[] = array(
 'onlineexam_student_id' => $this->input->post('onlineexam_student_id'),
 'onlineexam_question_id' => $this->input->post('question_id_' . $row_value),
 'select_option' => $_POST['radio' . $row_value],
 'attachment_name' => "",
 'attachment_upload_name' => "",
 );
 }
 } elseif (($_POST['question_type_' . $row_value]) == "true_false") {
 # code...
 if (isset($_POST['radio' . $row_value])) {
 $save_result[] = array(
 'onlineexam_student_id' => $this->input->post('onlineexam_student_id'),
 'onlineexam_question_id' => $this->input->post('question_id_' . $row_value),
 'select_option' => $_POST['radio' . $row_value],
 'attachment_name' => "",
 'attachment_upload_name' => "",
 );
 }
 } elseif (($_POST['question_type_' . $row_value]) == "multichoice") {
 # code...
 if (isset($_POST['checkbox' . $row_value])) {
 $save_result[] = array(
 'onlineexam_student_id' => $this->input->post('onlineexam_student_id'),
 'onlineexam_question_id' => $this->input->post('question_id_' . $row_value),
 'select_option' => json_encode($_POST['checkbox' . $row_value]),
 'attachment_name' => "",
 'attachment_upload_name' => "",
 );
 }
 } elseif (($_POST['question_type_' . $row_value]) == "descriptive") {
 # code...
 if (isset($_POST['answer' . $row_value]) || (isset($_FILES["attachment" . $row_value]) && !empty($_FILES["attachment" . $row_value]['name']))) {
 $inst_array = array(
 'onlineexam_student_id' => $this->input->post('onlineexam_student_id'),
 'onlineexam_question_id' => $this->input->post('question_id_' . $row_value),
 'select_option' => $_POST['answer' . $row_value],
 );

 $file_name = "";
 $upload_file_name = "";
 if (isset($_FILES["attachment" . $row_value]) && !empty($_FILES["attachment" . $row_value]['name'])) {
 $file_name = $_FILES["attachment" . $row_value]["name"];
 $fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES["attachment" . $row_value]["name"]);
 $upload_file_name = time() . uniqid(rand()) . '.' . $fileInfo['extension'];
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachment" . $row_value]["tmp_name"], "./uploads/onlinexam_images/" . $upload_file_name);

 }
 $inst_array['attachment_name'] = $file_name;
 $inst_array['attachment_upload_name'] = $upload_file_name;

 $save_result[] = $inst_array;
 }
 }

 }

 $this->onlineexamresult_model->add($save_result);
 $this->onlineexam_model->updateExamResult($this->input->post('onlineexam_student_id'));
 redirect('user/onlineexam', 'refresh');
 }
 } else {

 }
 }
```

model:

```
   public function add($data_insert)
   {

   $this->db->trans_begin();

   if (!empty($data_insert)) {

   $this->db->insert_batch('onlineexam_student_results', $data_insert);
   }

   if ($this->db->trans_status() === false) {
   $this->db->trans_rollback();
   return false;
   } else {
   $this->db->trans_commit();
   return true;
   }
   }
```

Comment: set an unique index for the pair of: onlineexam_student_id and onlineexam_question_id and then read on [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Is this a multiple choice test? answers "a" and "d" where given. More concerning looks the other pair, it's 2 times the exact same answer for the same question, but at different times. Much more looks like a problem to me...

Comment: Please can you explain this more?  @HonkderHase

Comment: @Esepebbles my advice is not to do that. Logic wise user should know what was the result each time he wrote the exam.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, but the previous attempt scores are being calculated with the new attempt scores. If there are 4 questions and user attempts twice, its shows 8 questions which are duplicates.